# Spring Template Project Not Working with Cloud Foundry Server

Tags: spring, model-view-controller, maven, project, cloud-foundry

I'm currently trying to create a spring mvc project using STS tool.
So I created one using the Spring Template Project provided by STS. I tried to run it using tomcat server and it's doing fine. But when I tried using the VMare Cloud Foundry Server, it is not working anymore. I'm having this kind of error:

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.lang.NullPointerException
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:538)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:370)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:238)
org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:262)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1157)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:927)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:827)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:778)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
```

Comment: Hi, can you post the application logs output. You can get these by running "vmc logs <application name>"

Comment: Hi, I didn't install the vmc. I just use the sts tool for this project. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

more likely the error is related to spring version. I got it deployed with springVersion = 3.1.1.RELEASE

Answer (score 0):

You can view the logs by opening the CloudFoundry plugin from the "Servers" pane. Click the "Remote Systems View" link and then use use the "Remote Systems" tab to navigate the applications and their logs files.

See the Skitch capture below;

http://goo.gl/603vT

Comment: Hi, I have a pretty long logs there, but as I can see, the logs has no errors, it's all just info. I can also see that the my controller is properly called since it executes the codes in my controller, but the problem is when it returns the page, it's having an error. This does not happen when I run it on my Local Tomcat Server, but only when I run it on cloud foundry. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try right clicking on your application, then go onto Maven --> Update Dependencies.

Once you do that, you should restart your app on cloud foundry and it should just work.